# Express Error Handling: Sending a Message to Frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I'm having some trouble error handling my authentication API calls. When I send the 500 status from Express, my frontend (Vue in this case) only picks up the message *Request failed with status code 500* rather than something more helpful for triage like *this is the worst error ever* (in the example below).

In the below example, when I call '/post' from the API, I throw an error which is handled by my custom middleware. The middleware successfully handles the error and sends the appropriate status to my frontend, but I can't figure out how to send useful messages (e.g. 'this is the worst error ever') / access them in the front end.

Is this a common use case? Am I doing anything obviously wrong? Does the message I send come up in the (err) parameter, or do I need to add a resp parameter?

**Express Route for '/login'**

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    throw Error('this is the worst error ever')
})
```

**Custom express error handler**

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500).send({
        error: {
            status: err.status || 500,
            message: err.message || 'Internal Server Error',
        },
    });
});
```

**Handle the API Response in Vue**

```
login (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    UserService.login(this.username, this.password) //this is simple axios post call 
    .catch((err) => {
         this.loginStatus = err.message
         return
    })
}
```

Comment: Is another way to do this to set locals in the error handler in express, and then access them later in vue?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer to this for those that find this helpful. The err that is caught has a response variable. This is where the data is sent via the express *send* command. See corrected code below for the frontend:

```
login (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    UserService.login(this.username, this.password) //this is simple axios post call 
    .catch((err) => {
         this.loginStatus = err.response.data.message
         return
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add:

```
Throw new Error()
```

instead of

```
Throw Error
```

If you are making an asynchronous calling you can do this

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  fs.readFile('/file-does-not-exist', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       next(err) // Pass errors to Express.
    } else {
       res.send(data)
    }
  })
})
```

Code should look like this:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
   throw new Error('this is the worst error ever')
})
```

Check this in [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Comment: the new Error() vs Error() shouldn't make a difference, as that part of the app is working. It's